# How to flatten Verilog bus to individual wires using Yosys

Tags: yosys

Simple question here.  Is there a method in Yosys to flatten arrays? i.e.:

`wire [1:0] rdata;` becomes `wire rdata_1; wire rdata_0;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer.  Not sure when it should be called.  After `proc` seems to work.

```
proc
opt
splicenets -format __ # <---
[..]
```

Comment: A side note: I think this command is now called `splitnets`